# Material UI GridListTileBar override not working

Tags: css, overriding, material-ui

This material UI code generates a `ul` with a bunch of `<img />` tags as the `li`. I'm trying to override the width for these `<img />` tags, but for some reason material UI classes override doesn't seem to be registering. Anyone have any clues about this?

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  tile: {
    width: '100%',
  }
});

function SingleLineGridList(props) {
  const { classes, tileData } = props;

  return (
    <div>
     <GridList cols={2.5}>
       {tileData.map(tile => (
         <GridListTile classes={{root: classes.tile}} key={tile.img}>
           <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
         </GridListTile>
       ))}
     </GridList>
   </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SingleLineGridList);
```

Comment: I can't tell from your code, but it's possible you could have forgotten to use withStyles when exporting your code, which would make it so that none of your custom styles end up getting used.

Comment: Hey Stephen, forgot to add it, but I do have the withStyles line in my code!